# In codeigniter Redirection to custom html page after 500 error

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, redirect, apache2

In codeigniter how do I redirect to a custom HTML page when 500 error occurs?

I have tried following code in .htaccess but it does not work:

ErrorDocument `500 /errors/error_500.html`

`error_500.html` is my custom HTML page and its location is `application/errors`

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Answer (score 1):

The [ErrorDocument](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument) directive, when supplied a local URL path, expects the path to be fully qualified from the [DocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#documentroot). In your case, this means that the actual path to the `ErrorDocument` is

```
ErrorDocument 500 /path/errors/error_500.html
```

try

```
ErrorDocument 500 http://localhost/errors/error_500.html
```

When you corrected it in your second try, the reason you see that page instead is because `http://localhost/errors/error_500.html` doesn't exist, hence the bit about there being a 500 error in locating the error handling document.

Answer (score 1):

In Codeigniter actually it has a custom 500 error page.

So if you find your getting a generic 500 error page means, that it could be `Apache overriding the codeiginter  500 error page`.

You could also try to override it in the `.htaccess to direct it` to your own custom 500.html,

but then you will miss out any of the error information provided by codeiginter:

`ErrorDocument 500 /errors/error_500.html`

You could also edit the codeiginter 500 error page found in `/application/errors/`. I think it is the `error_php.php` file.